# List of desktop GIS FOSS case studies

Tags: open-source-gis, osgeo

I think we should create a list of best desktop GIS FOSS case studies. First of all this list will be useful to anyone who considers desktop GIS FOSS for a project as an viable alternative.

Comment: I guess this should be community wiki?

Comment: you can also do a question per domain. i.e. FOSS experience in Transportation, Bio, Planning, Bio, etc ...

Comment: im new to all this, if community wiki means that anyone can edit, then sure

Comment: i'm not sure if community wiki 'questions' supposed to have answers or we can always edit question itself?

Comment: When you're asking a question where the collection of answers *is* the answer (here, all the various case studies) you should make it community wiki.  Each case study should get its own answer, and then people can vote them up or down based on how interesting/useful that particular study is.

Comment: I think it's acceptable to edit the original question, but it's probably better to have a single canonical answer below the question so the question shows as answered

Comment: to restate Jason's point more explicitly: cut the "to start things off..." studies and paste them as an answer :)

Comment: well it's a wiki, anyone can do it, right? :)

Answer (score 8):

Please add to this answer as you find more!

### QGIS

http://www.qgis.org

- [Working with QGIS in a spatial data infrastructure of Jalisco in Mexico](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/qgis-case-studies/jalisco-mexico.html)
- [Quantum GIS and GRASS in Biogeographical Research in the Iberian Peninsula](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/qgis-case-studies/evora-portugal.html)
- [QGIS - an interesting instrument for forestry planning concepts at local and regional level](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/qgis-case-studies/basel-switzerland.html)
- [QGIS in the governmental FOSSGIS stack of the Canton of Solothurn in Switzerland](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/qgis-case-studies/solothurn-switzerland.html)
- [QGIS as major GIS software in the Laboratory on Experimental and Applied Geography](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/qgis-case-studies/brno-czech-republic.html)
- [QGIS and GRASS applied to paleontological survey in Western Portugal](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/qgis-case-studies/torres-vedras-portugal.html)

### OpenGeo

http://opengeo.org/

- [Advanced WEB based vector editing for Swedish Postal Service](http://opengeo.org/publications/sweco/)
- [WEB based trip planner built on OpenGeo stack](http://opengeo.org/publications/trimet/)
- [GeoServer WFS-T services maintained by Information Centre of the Ministry of Agriculture and Forestry in Finland](http://opengeo.org/publications/tike/)
- [Netherlands WEB based national infrastructure of canals, dams and dikes map portal](http://opengeo.org/publications/rijkswaterstaat/)
- [City of New York WFS/GML map viewer](http://opengeo.org/publications/nyc-doitt/)
- [State of Massachusetts geoportal (851 data layers, ~1TB of data)](http://opengeo.org/publications/massgis/)
- [Collaborative map for Western Australia's land data authority (Landgate), using OpenLayers and a Versioning extension to the Web Feature Service Standard](http://opengeo.org/publications/landgate/)

Answer (score 3):

**GRASS**

http://grass.osgeo.org/applications/

In this GRASS applications list, several case studies are linked.

Answer (score 2):

**uDig**

Found some on their [Gallery page](http://udig.refractions.net/gallery/).

- [Arbonaut](http://udig.refractions.net/gallery/arbonaut/)
- [Line Cleaner](http://udig.refractions.net/gallery/linecleaner/)
- [DEWS](http://udig.refractions.net/gallery/dews/)
- [DIVA GIS](http://udig.refractions.net/gallery/cgiar/)
- [JGrass](http://udig.refractions.net/gallery/jgrass/)
- [Eurobios](http://udig.refractions.net/gallery/eurobios/)

Answer (score 2):

OSGeo is offering the gallery: http://gallery.osgeo.org/ which links to several use cases.

Answer (score 0):

**PostGIS**

Some useful links for PostGIS

- [BostonGIS](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_tut01)
- [giswiki.org](http://www.giswiki.org/wiki/PostGIS_Tutorial)
- [OpenGeo](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS)
- [Postgisonline](http://www.postgisonline.org/)
- [Geoalchemy](http://www.geoalchemy.org/tutorial.html)
  and
- [Post gis manual](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/) (1.5.2 edition)